# spring boot could show sql even use JdbcTemplate directly

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate

spring boot project, used `JdbcTemplate`, and want to show sql which is executed, the configuration is as below

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

but nothing output, it seems above configuration only support `spring data jpa`,  So I'd like to know does exist some manner could show sql even used `JdbcTemplate` directly?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a reason why the property is named `spring.jpa` something: it is to indicate you that it relates to JPA in some form.

If you're using `JdbcTemplate`, you're not using JPA hence that property can't have any effect. You can enable logging for the `org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate` class

```
logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=debug
```

Comment: thanks! `2016-03-11 18:57:00.168 DEBUG 19587 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [select mobile, max(total_amount) total_amount from user_draw_log where total_amount > 0 group by mobile order by max(total_amount) desc limit ?, ?;]
`